# Есть число int, например 12345678, и нужно его преобразовать в массив

Tags: java, массивы, числа

```
int a = 12345678;  //Вход

int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };  //Выход
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам понадобится использовать остаток от деления на 10 и целочисленное деление

Comment: Я так понял, что надо просто число перевести в массив, где каждый элемент - это число по порядку?
А почему бы не перевести число в строку, а ее в массив?

Comment: Самый простой и прозрачный вариант, это привести число в строку и дальше посимвольно перевести в нужные числа вычитанием: `input.charAt(i) - '0'`. К примеру `int a = "53793".charAt(3) - '0';` даст число 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

идём в гугл и пишем запрос `число в массив java`
а лучше `stackoverflow: число в массив java` чтобы с данного сайта выборка была

открываем ссылку `Convert an integer to an array of characters : java`

хочешь так

```
int i = 1234;
char[] chars = ("" + i).toCharArray();
```

хочешь этак

```
String.valueOf(1234).toCharArray();
```

а если знаешь английский, то `Convert an integer to an array of digits`

можно так

```
String temp = Integer.toString(guess);
int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
{
    newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

можно этак

```
int temp = test;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do{
    array.add(temp % 10);
    temp /= 10;
} while  (temp > 0);
```

и там ещё с десяток других ответов, так что
учись гуглить. ответы данный вопрос датируются 2012 годом, выбирай какой больше нравиться, а в идеале проработать и попробовать каждый из ответов

Comment: Спасибо  большое

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mainn {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        aVoid(12345678);
    }

    public static void aVoid(int number) {
        int len = String.valueOf(Math.abs(number)).length();//Узнать длинну числа (будет 8)

        int temp_number = number;//создать переменную для теста
        int[] a1 = new int[len];//создать массив с длинной указанной в len

        for (int i = len - 1; i > -1; i--){//заполнить массив с конца

            a1[i] = temp_number%10;//присвоить остаток от деления этому числу

            //temp_number -= (temp_number%10);//остаток от деления записать в последний элемент массива, потом в пред последний и тд
            temp_number /= 10;//разделить число на 10 что бы дальше считать остатки от деления
            System.out.println(temp_number);//чисто показать результат выполнения
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));//показать готовый массив
    }
}
==================================================================
ВЫВОД

1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Вроде работает)))

Comment: кому не лень можете сделать другим способом, и максимально кратко и понятно

Comment: В целом неплохо, только можно убрать лишний код: `temp_number -= (temp_number%10);`  так как при целочисленном делении младший разряд всё равно "исчезнет", и для отрицательных чисел стоит добавить обработку

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал

Comment: с отрицательными числами кстати всё нормально работает, ничего менять не нужно

Answer (score 0):

1. Вычисляете размер массива `size`, например, при помощи деления в цикле, пока входное число `n` больше 0, минимальный размер равен 1.
2. Создаёте массив размером `size`.
3. При помощи деления и вычисления остатка от деления на 10, заполняете массив (скорее всего в обратном порядке, так как сначала будут получаться младшие разряды числа).

Готовый код не приводится, так как задание явно учебное.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую через деление на 10, покажу что получилось